# Does initialising an object in "using" block disposes it of outside the block?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have some code which looks like this:

```
Object o;
using (SqlConnection sql = GetSqlConnection) {
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = GetSqlCommand()) {
        using (Datareader dr = GetDataReader()) {
            o = new Object();
            while (dr.read()) {
                //do something
            }
        }
        if (o == null) // RESHARPER SAYS THAT THIS WILL ALWAYS BE TRUE
            //do something
    }
}
```

The place where I check for `o == null`, ReSharper says that this command will always be true. I don't understand this behaviour; do all the objects initialised in `using` block get disposed of, or only the ones which are created with `using` statement.

Comment: Looks like either resharper is wrong, or this snippet doesn't behave exactly like your code.

Comment: I can't paste the actual code, but this is exactly how my entire code is behaving.

Comment: Then the only option left is a resharper bug. You can test easily enough: put an else clause and see if the compiler gives you a warning for unreachable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the using block is closed, it will call Dispose() on that object, which, depending on the implementation of IDisposable, may set the object to null. However, "o" in your case isn't IDisposable or in a using block, and I'm willing to believe ReSharper has a bug in this case, because when I have the exact same code in my installation, it prompts me to replace

```
if(o == null)
```

with false, exactly the opposite of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Does initialising an object in “using” block disposes it of outside
>   the block?

**No**. [Here is proof.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/23ZQBJ%243)

The object you're using will be disposed, of course (that's the whole point of using), but things done within the block aren't affected. This is a new scope, though, so you'd get the warning with **this** code:

```
Object o;
using (SqlConnection sql = GetSqlConnection) {
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = GetSqlCommand()) {
        using (Datareader dr = GetDataReader()) {
            Object o = new Object();
            while (dr.read()) {
                //do something
            }
        }
        if (o == null) // RESHARPER SAYS THAT THIS WILL ALWAYS BE TRUE
            //do something
    }
}
```

(note the declaration of a second object o in the inner scope).

Answer (score 1):

If your code is exactly as written and Resharper is really complaining about the line you indicated, then it is wrong.

In fact, ReSharper has it exactly backwards: the comparison is redundant because it will *never* be true. You set `o` to a `new Object()` immediately, so it will never be `null`. The `using` block has no effect on the value of variables other than the one you put in the opening statement. Upon leaving a `using` block, that one instance is disposed of by calling `IDisposable.Dispose` on it, and it goes out of scope.

However, I do want to correct one huge misconception you seem to have: ***disposing of an object does not set it to null***. The following code *will* still crash when it tries to close an already-disposed object:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
conn.Open();
conn.Dispose();

if (conn != null)
{
  conn.Close();
}
```

"Being disposed" is a condition that applies to instances of objects; it means their resources have been cleaned up and they cannot be safely used anymore. "Being null" is a condition that applies to *variables*; it means they do not reference *any* instance of their defined type, disposed-of or otherwise.

The `using` keyword and `IDisposable` interface are using to manage the is-disposed-of state of instances of objects. They have no effect on the is-a-null-value state of variables in your program.